Angular 17.0.X update to 17.3.3 failing - issue with dependencies
We have an Angular app that we have upgraded to 17.0.X and now we want to get it running to the latest version as of the time of writing - 17.3.X. We have updated the dependencies but we are seeing strange issues from transitive dependencies being pulled.
Before upgrade package.json:
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.5",
    "@ngx-dropzone/cdk": "^17.1.0",
    "@ngx-dropzone/material": "^17.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.5",
    "ngx-mat-timepicker": "^17.0.1",
    "ol": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "vis-data": "^7.1.9",
    "vis-timeline": "^7.7.3",
    "vis-util": "^5.0.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}

After upgrade package.json:
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.3",
    "@ngx-dropzone/cdk": "^17.3.0",
    "@ngx-dropzone/material": "^17.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.5",
    "ngx-mat-timepicker": "^17.1.0",
    "ol": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "vis-data": "^7.1.9",
    "vis-timeline": "^7.7.3",
    "vis-util": "^5.0.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}

The error that we are getting is
'Log files:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-09T17_39_16_916Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: ui@0.0.0
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.0.6
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.3" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@17.3.3
node_modules/@angular/compiler
  peer @angular/compiler@"17.3.3" from @angular/localize@17.3.3
  node_modules/@angular/localize
    @angular/localize@"^17.3.3" from the root project
    peerOptional @angular/localize@"^17.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.3.3
    node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
      dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.3" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.


try npm install --force or  npm install --legacy-peer-deps

@pl-jay npm install --force works - but would that cause any issues down the line or at this moment?

That's fine I guess I also had the same issue while angular version upgrade using force method fixed that... So far no issues

Getting more or less the same issue when trying to upgrade from v16.
Very weird peer deps issues coming out. Don't want to resort to --force flag.

Your versions seem correct. Try to remove node_modules folder and run npm install again.
You can also try with flag --legacy-peer-deps, but that shouldnt be required

I removed the node modules and ran npm install but it does not work, I am getting the same errors. npm install --force works - but would that cause any issues down the line?
